# how to change Kafka broker list ip

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 3 Kafka brokers running in a isolated network region, my client can not connect them directly, so I have to use a VIP(virtual ip) to connect the brokers.

For example:

my brokers' IP are: `10.5.1.5, 10.5.1.6, 10.5.1.7`,

my VIPs' ip are: `200.100.1.5, 200.100.1.6, 200.100.1.7`, they one to one paired.

So when I indicate the bootstrap list as `200.100.1.5`, the cluster response me the mixed VIPs and Broker ips, such as: `10.5.1.5, 10.5.1.6, 200.100.1.5, 200.100.1.6 ...`, then the connection failed, because my program can not reach broker's ip, only can reach VIPs.

My current configuration as following, it responses both IP and VIP:

```
listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://:8080

advertised.listeners=EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://200.100.1.5:8080,INTERNAL://10.5.1.5:9092

listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT

inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

How can I let Kafka only response the VIP list please.

I've got the answer, it could be the following:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://200.100.1.5:8080
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.5.1.5:9092
And remove the listener.security and inter.broker.
```

Comment: Are your virtual IPs implemented inside of the nodes hosting kafka, or some external proxy/router? i.e. does your first kafka node know that it's on 200.100.1.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the broker setting called `advertised.listeners` to tell your brokers to include a different IP/hostname in their response to clients.

`advertised.listeners`:

> Listeners to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use, if different
>   than the `listeners` config property. In IaaS environments, this may
>   need to be different from the interface to which the broker binds. If
>   this is not set, the value for `listeners` will be used. Unlike
>   `listeners` it is not valid to advertise the 0.0.0.0 meta-address.

In your example, for the first broker you can have:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://200.100.1.5:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.5.1.5:9092
```

Comment: Changing the producer code for this is a really bad idea. If you do that only your hacked clients will be able to connect to your cluster. The broker settings I listed are made exactly for that.

Comment: If you see an exception, please paste it here. The snippet I posted is just an example, the exact values for these 2 settings depend on your configuration but using them, you can achieve what you asked. Please take time to read the docs for both `advertised.listeners` and `listeners` and understand how they work.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. You say your client connects fine but to which listener `EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT` or `INTERNAL` ?
I'm guessing you want your clients to use the `EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT` on 8080 and only have inter broker traffic on `INTERNAL` on 9092. Can you ensure your clients are indeed connecting to 8080 ?